# Does one remonstrate another or does one remonstrate with another?

Tags: prepositions, intransitive-verbs

If I am protesting forcefully the actions of another, let’s call him Joe, would it be better to say:

> I remonstrated Joe over his choice of words in that argument.

or would I say:

> I remonstrated *with* Joe over his choice of words in that argument.

Because he is the target of my remonstration, no?

---

Because close votes are collecting, let me explain why a simple internet search thus far has not led to me to a definitive answer:

The link supplied which suggests that *suggests that adding “with” is usual* was quite quickly found by me, and I didn’t think it necessary to state that I had come across that link, as the whole purpose of me asking would be negated if I had never heard someone say “aren’t you to use *with* with that verb?” I’m asking because I don’t know what the difference is when the target of the remonstration is present, versus when you’re discussing someone with whom you were remonstrating, for instance, if two editors were remonstrating the closing of a publisher. That would be an obvious use of *with* to connote multiple involved parties.

I don’t say *I beat with you*, whereas I might say *I debated you* or you might say *I debated with you*. Is *remonstrated* used in the same way as *debated* in this case, where you may choose or not choose to use *with* or is *with* required when using *remonstrated*?

---

More specifically, I said it as a direct statement to him “I remonstrated you” (a smaller clause from a larger sentence, with context)

Comment: http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/remonstrate

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remonstrate suggests that adding "with" is usual.

Comment: Thanks for the close votes, however, I don't think that you've actually cleared anything up. Precisely which is preferred, and why, or why is it acceptable to use "with", or why is it required to use with.

Comment: You haven't asked that; you've asked a General Reference question -- it can conclusively be answered with a single link or even two. I suspect the answer to the supplementary comment is "It just is", but that's likely to be available with a little research of your own too. What have you looked up to find the answer? (It saves others repeating that if you state it in the question)

Comment: No it can't. I don't understand it, and I read those before asking this question. Therefore, it can't be answered. I'm happy that you have some fancy degree in wordsmithery, but I do not. I have found that if I have to ask, it wasn't clear to begin with.

Comment: @jcolebrand You **seemed** to ask "would it be better to say *I remonstrated Joe* or *I remonstrated with Joe*?". That is a simple binary question, and the answer is "the latter - go see a dictionary". I'm happy to believe you that there's a more profound question in there, but I can't work out what it is. Are you asking which is more common? http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=remonstrated+him%2Cremonstrated+with+him&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share= How's this?

Comment: @jcolebrand  Please don't take offense. Your original question gave Andrew Leach and Billy only a choice between between two alternatives, and that *was* a GR question. They did exactly what they're supposed to do, and you have now done exactly what you're [supposed to do](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/12/you-could-look-it-up/?cb=1): added a great deal of additional information which completely changes the complexion of your question.

Comment: I felt the entirety of the question was summed up with "which do I use" and even your answer @StoneyB is that there are varying use cases. The fact that I'm immediately closevoted without being queried about the potential unknowns of my question _is_ an attack on _any_ SE site, and I call my own users out for that as well on [dba.se]. Comment first, then downvote, then closevote. You don't just closevote on something that obviously has content, as your own answer has given. Must we really do the song and dance for every consulted source, as I checked the front page of Google and had no answer.

Comment: Additionally, just the mere act of googling for a result in this day and age is inconsistent, as Google refines each result page for the specific searcher, and not for a generic all-are-equal results list. Your results are often _not_ my results, so my searches give different history than your searches. You can no longer say "just google it" as you don't know what the results for that person will be.

Comment: @jcolebrand Please calm down. I neither closevoted nor downvoted your post (nor told you to google anything). I am still waiting to find out what your question is. You still seem to be asking questions like "which should I use when?", and I don't see how we haven't answered you. This isn't a snide comment - please tell me what you still don't know, and I will try to help you.

Comment: I don't understand which case is required _when_. Obviously there are two use-cases for the usage of the word. That much is apparent from the discussion. Why would I choose to use "with" and why would I choose not to?

Comment: @jcolebrand When you are opposing a person, you are *remonstrating with* them ("I remonstrated with Joe"). When you disagree with a claim / object / person / person's behaviour / whatever, and you want to oppose it, you will *remonstrate* some words of opposition - most commonly these words of opposition will be direct speech (like in the Oxford dictionary example) or a clause of indirect speech starting with *that* (like in StoneyB's example below). The word is similar to "argue" in these cases ("I argued with Joe", "I argued that he was wrong", "'I find your behaviour appalling,' I argued").

Comment: @Billy  An excellent analogy. I urge you to post it, appropriating any of my answer you're partial to, and then I will delete my answer and upvote yours.

Comment: @StoneyB Okay, I'll post it.

Comment: That was actually spot on what the hell I couldn't figure out from the online dictionaries

Comment: Thank you everyone for clearing that up, even at the expense of my exasperation ;-) {PS: my heart rate was never up @Billy I just have the capacity to appear extremely agitated, even when calm, and to remain calm, even when agitated ... sometimes a curse}

Comment: And now we've got all that sorted - Welcome to ELU, jcolebrand. We're very ornery about General Reference questions around here, because we get distressing quantities of questions that are completely answerable from even the most primitive dictionary; so, yeah, we want you to do the dictionary-song-and-dance so we don't have to do the do-you-really-have-a-question-or-are-you-just-too-lazy-or-too-ignorant-to-look-it-up-song-and-dance.

Comment: @jcolebrand :) Glad to help.

Comment: Aye, but at ~1500 rep on here, I feel as tho I've gotten past the stage of "durrr, where's merriam webster"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are basically two uses:

1. The use as an *intransitive* verb: when you are opposing a person, you are *remonstrating with* them, e.g. "I remonstrated with Joe".
2. The use as a *transitive* verb: when you wish to oppose an action / claim / object / person / person's behaviour, you can *remonstrate* some words of opposition. This will occur in two contexts:

   - Direct speech, e.g. "'I find your behaviour appalling,' I remonstrated".
   - Indirect speech: usually a clause beginning with *that* (though, as always, the *that* can be omitted), e.g. "I remonstrated that I found Joe's behaviour appalling".

All of these uses are comparable to the verb "argue":

1. "I argued with Joe"
2. - "'I find your behaviour appalling,' I argued"
   - "I argued that I found Joe's behaviour appalling"

[This](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=remonstrated%20him,remonstrated%20with%20him&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) ngrams page shows that there have been occasional instances in literature of "remonstrated him" rather than "remonstrated with him", but they are rare enough to be treated as essentially mistakes in my opinion (you have to set smoothing to 0 to even see them, and even then they are three isolated blips).

Comment: Please show references. I don't agree that either the quotative usage or the usage with a that-clause are transitive usages (though analyses here differ).  Dictionary pronouncements on a transitive uasge (or not), and which types of sentences are considered acceptable, would carry more weight than homespun examples.

Answer (score 2):

The [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/remonstrate),  [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remonstrate), and [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/remonstrate?q=remonstrate) online dictionaries all call for *with* before the person to whom a remonstrance is directed.

Traditional grammar, which these dictionaries follow, treats this construction as an intransitive verb followed by a prepositional phrase; I prefer to regard it as a transitive phrasal verb, *remonstrate with*.

At any rate, in my experience what you call the “target” (an apt word, by the way) is always designated by the preposition *with*. *OED* offers uses with *to*, but marks these as obsolete.

Merriam-Webster also gives a transitive sense, with no examples; but the object of that verb would be the substance of the remonstrance, not the person to whom it is directed:

> I remonstrated [with Joe] that his choice of words was entirely inappropriate.

Comment: Now why don't they spell it out in such plain English? Nowhere on the MW page do I even _see_ that usage? (it _could_ have been the insurmountable number of ads present) Notice also that your usage provides a case where _with_ isn't necessary. Again I'm unsure of the proper usage, as you've given two distinct rules.

Comment: @jcolebrand The example is not spelled out in MW; they use the words "intransitive" and "transitive" to indicate the use. The same goes for *debate*: the intransitive goes with *with* and the transitive specifies what is being debated. So you can't say "I debated you" unless the person you're talking to is the person who you were discussing with others.

Comment: @jcolebrand  I've edited my answer. Dictionaries can't include everything, even the monstrous and magisterial *OED*; certainly not the low-end versions you get free online. I would recommend consulting corpora such as COCA and BNC at [BYU](http://corpus.byu.edu/), but everybody tells me they're too hard to use.

Comment: But that's the only time I would say "I debated you", what other case would there be for using that particular phrase?

Comment: @jcolebrand There wouldn't; but again, in your question it appears that *I debated you* is equated to *I debated with you* with no distinction between them -- especially since it's immediately followed by *I remonstrated you* which has been shown to be incorrect.

Comment: Are COCA and BNC free to the general public and online resources?

Comment: @jcolebrand I think Andrew is saying that "I debated you" means "I was talking about you (with some other people)", not "I debated with you". (If you use it in the latter sense, it might be regional slang - I've never heard it, but I can imagine it being plausible.)

Comment: I would only use the later case in exasperation, but in the case of "I remonstrated you" that was specifically the usage I used earlier, and then was told I used it incorrectly, so I ventured here to learn _why_ I was wrong, which I have hence learned.

Comment: And I encourage you to not delete the answer Stoney

Comment: @jcolebrand I'll leave it then; but Billy's is better and more useful.

Comment: Both are useful :D

Comment: @jcolebrand- Wordnik is a good site to use when looking for examples of usage: http://www.wordnik.com/words/remonstrated

Comment: @Jim Thanks for pointing that out - I wasn't aware of it either.

Comment: Collins mentions a transitive usage it labels archaic.

Answer (score 2):

All our examples are past tense, which makes the word a mouthful. And it is already a mouthful!

> "Remonstrate him," the cardinal said to the priest, looking down at
> the pauper.

> "A man thinks he is his ideas---so he must constantly be ready to
> remonstrate himself should he find himself mad with no response."

I think its cleaner to use present tense when possible. That said, the [ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=15&content=remonstrate%2Cremonstrated&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cremonstrate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cremonstrated%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cremonstrate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cremonstrated%3B%2Cc0) shows that the past tense is much more common.

Comment: But what licensing is there that _remonstrate_ can be used transitively, with a volitional theme / patient? The timeframe is at best a secondary consideration. The 1-grams you link to fail to address this totally.

Comment: Right on Edwin. <3